# Who is the second Hamlin in Hamlin, Hamlin and McGill?

Tags: better-call-saul

In Better Call Saul, the prequel of Breaking Bad, a successful Albuquerque lawyer firm called Hamlin, Hamlin and McGill is named after:

1. Howard Hamlin
2. Charles McGill
3. ??? Someone else called Hamlin ???

Who is the second Hamlin in Hamlin, Hamlin and McGill?

Comment: It wasn't explained so far, but it seems that there indeed was another Hamlin in the past. You may want to [read this discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/betterCallSaul/comments/2ybmin/who_is_the_second_hamlin_in_hamlin_hamlin_mcgill/).

Comment: It could be that Hamlin is so pretentious that he put his name twice... Or that it is his father (or late father) - that's usually how things work.

Comment: I'm reminded of "Eisenhower and Lutz", which had no Eisenhower - it just added prestige to Lutz.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

##### The other Hamlin is George Hamlin, Howard Hamlin's father.

It was mentioned by Howard in Season 2 Episode 8, "[Fifi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifi_(Better_Call_Saul))" that the other "H" in HHM, is his father (emphasis mine):

> Back in the day, right out of law school, I thought long and hard about hanging up my own shingle.
> [...]
> Oh, I was ready to take on the world, make a difference.
> **Dad** talked me out of it.
> **Wanted me to join the ranks here, throw another "H" in the firm's
> logo.**

In Season 3 Episode 5, "[Chicanery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicanery_(Better_Call_Saul))", Howard, while testifying under oath as a witness, was asked directly who the other Hamlin is in HHM. He again mentions that it is his father.

Howard's father's name, George Hamlin, was first mentioned in Season 4 Episode 1, "[Smoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_(Better_Call_Saul))":

> Charles joined George Hamlin's solo practice on Central Avenue
> in downtown Albuquerque. Over the course of 23 years, the two men
> built what became known as Hamlin Hamlin McGill into a nationally-recognized firm.

Comment: Congratulations, this answer is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1795/49).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson http://i.stack.imgur.com/P96Av.gif